# Linux Powershell client : Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapIn & Connect-VBRServer

Tags: powershell

Please advice me how to use : `Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapIn` & `Connect-VBRServer` on a Linux Ubuntu Powershell client

Here is what I tried:

```
#$psversiontable Output                                                                                             
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      6.1.0-preview.2
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    v6.1.0-preview.2
OS                             Linux 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

`#Connect-VBRServer Output:`

> Connect-VBRServer : The term 'Connect-VBRServer' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + Connect-VBRServer
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Connect-VBRServer:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

`#Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapIn Output:`

> Add-PSSnapin : The term 'Add-PSSnapin' is not recognized as the name
>   of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
>   spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
>   is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-PSSnapin VeeamPSSnapIn
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Add-PSSnapin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

According to Veeam Knowledge Base the PowerShell Module is installed with a [Windows Setup File](https://www.veeam.com/kb1489). Maybe ask Veeam directly if it's planned to support Linux?